# How to use angularjs $anchorScroll on div only if div is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm  using angularjs to develop a web application. I have several nested `div`. Each of them correspond to an item that the user can select. 
A good example of my `div` display is in the official angularJs documentation : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/qncMfyJpuP2r0VUz0ax8?p=preview 
In my code each `div` have a `ng-click="gotoAnchor(x)"` event so when I click on a `div` if it is partially hidden, it pull it up on the page and the user can see all the clicked `div`. 
But I have a header in my page so the first `div` with an anchor and a click event is not directly at the top of the page. And if I click on the first div, it will scroll and the header won't be visible. 
So my question is, is there a way to activate the anchor only if the `div` isn't fully displayed on the screen ? 
If you have an other solution than anchors, I take it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the issue is that when using `$anchorScroll` your header is either

**a**: Being covered up by the div scrolled into frame,

or

**b** Partially covering up the div that is scrolled into frame.

Either way there are two solutions you should review:

## First

make sure you're employing CSS to properly layer your elements, your header (if fixed) should have a `z-index` that supersedes your divs.

```
.header  { position: fixed; top:0; width: 100%; z-index: 99}
.content { position: relative; margin-top: 10px; z-index: 1;}
```

**REMEMBER** Z-index only works on positional elements (See [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp))

### Second

Employ `$anchorScroll.yOffset` to make sure your scroll distance is bumped down to compensate for the header height. As seen in the Angular docs, you can use this method in your application:

```
.run(['$anchorScroll', function($anchorScroll) {
  $anchorScroll.yOffset = 50;   // always scroll by 50 extra pixels
}])
```

Update `50` to be the pixel height of your header.

### Regarding visibility

There are a few great libraries and directives for checking the visibility of an element - try https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview as you can specify whether you want to enable an action when only the top, bottom or none of the div is visible.

**Note** Posistioning the first `div` correctly on the page will prevent any scroll from being necessary as seen in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dXUz1OHMNeTBb5tkTHnp?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try this solution adapted to my application and see what happen. But I'm not sure you understood what I mean. For exemple, in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dXUz1OHMNeTBb5tkTHnp?p=preview), the second div is fully displayed. If we click on the button "go to anchor 2", it will put the div with anchor2 id at the top of the page. In my application I don't want this behaviour if the div is fully displayed. Only if it is half displayed on the screen (if we can see the top of the div but not all the div).

Comment: Updated answer - see https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview for a directive that handles visibility calls.